Running Buildroot make through python 3.7 subprocess.run() stops in middle of process before timeout
I'm creating Buildroot images for Raspberry-Pi 3 ARM64 through a Jenkins job that runs a python 3.7 program.
The jenkin job runs in an ubuntu 22.04 LTS container and I'm trying to build sdcar.img files for Buildroot 2021.08.x and 2020.08.x.
This process was successful when building an ARM32 QEMU machine and when building a Raspberry-Pi 3 ARM32 image. With ARM64 Raspberry-Pi 3 image, I see the make output stopping a little after

Generating filesystem image rootfs.tar

with the last line is

ln -snf /buildroot/output/staging

No sdcard.img file is created.
Initially I was running
run = subprocess.run(["/bin/bash", "-c", "make 2>&1 | tee <path>/output.log"], check=True, timeout=JOB_CONSTANTS.CLI_COMMANDS_TIMEOUT, capture_output=True, text = True)

log.debug(f"{command} stdout output was:\n{run.stdout}")
log.debug(f"{command} stderr output was:\n{run.stderr}")

And then, thinking stdout might have been overloaded, I tried to change the make command to
"make > <path>/output.log 2>&1"

But that doesn't change a thing. The timeout is 3 hours and the make command run takes about 20 minutes.
To replace running make menuconfig my python code takes a .config file generated with menuconfig for everything that I need on the image, on a similar ubuntu machine and replacing the .config cloned from git. Before that I run make raspberrypi3_64_defconfig via subprocess as well.
Maybe there are other files that are changed besides .config when running menuconfig?
